# Error when running livesync on device

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I'm having trouble running sync on my iOS device using NativeScript with Angular2.

The following command works well:

```
tns run ios --device <device_id>
```

But when I try to run like this:

```
tns livesync ios --watch --device <device_id>
```

I get the following error:

```
***** Fatal JavaScript exception - application has been terminated. *****
Native stack trace:
1   0xd74aab -[TNSRuntime executeModule:referredBy:]
2   0xac487 main
registered for type RadSideDrawer.
3   0x1d0af50b <redacted>
JavaScript stack trace:
1   @file:///app/tns_modules/ui/core/dependency-observable.js:73:28
JavaScript error:
file:///app/tns_modules/ui/core/dependency-observable.js:73:28: JS ERROR Error: Property showOverNavigation already
```

The showOverNavigation is from the sidedrawer plugin that I'm using. But I have found other people on having the same kind of issue with other plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and I solve running the command:

> tns run ios --release

with only the real device connected, that makes the app works without error.
Also in the new version of tns the command livesynch is now replaced by the 'run' command.
But with the '--release' part I cannot have all the console.log in the terminal visible.

Comment: Related ticket@nativescript-cli: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2371